# How to control what appears in the $_SERVER array?

Tags: php, apache

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths,
>   and script locations. **The entries in this array are created by the
>   web server.** There is no guarantee that every web server will provide
>   any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed
>   here.

Are we able to configure the web server to enable and/or disable entries in the `$_SERVER` array?

For example, can we stop the web server from populating the `$_SERVER` array with the request headers, e.g. `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']` etc?

<sub>Using PHP 5.3.26, Apache 2.2.24.</sub>

Comment: Why would one want do this? The information is useful and expected by code. If YOUR code doesn't need it, ignore that array. Or `unset()` the stuff that you do not want.

Answer (score 0):

maybe via UnsetEnv see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html

untested.